# signalr avoid login repeat on load client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr-hub

I am using signalR pushnotification service.

I have created a partial view. Inside partial view. Here is my client side code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var objHub;
            $(function () {
                objHub = $.connection.AnilHub;

                loadClientMethods(objHub);

                $.connection.hub.start()
                    .done(function () { objHub.server.connect();
 console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id); }
// at the same time i want to insert into database to set user is online.

objHub.server.login('user1');
)
                    .fail(function () { console.log('Could not Connect!'); });


            function loadClientMethods(objHub) {

                objHub.client.getMessages = function (message) {
                    $('#divMessage').append('<div><p>' + message + '</p></div>');

                    var height = $('#divMessage')[0].scrollHeight;
                    $('#divMessage').scrollTop(height);
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Hub Code

```
[HubName("MyHub")]
    public class MainHub : Hub
    {
 public void Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                string userGroup = "test";

                var id = Context.ConnectionId;

                Groups.Add(id, userGroup);

                Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, userGroup);
            }
            catch
            {
                Clients.Caller.NoExistAdmin();
            }
        }
 public void NotifyAllClients(string Message)
        {
            Clients.Group("test").getMessages(Message);
        }
public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            // Set status online on database

            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled = false)
        {
            // set status disconnct in database
            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }
}
}
```

Now I just want to avoid re-loading check of login. because everytime I refresh the page it will call the connect method and call the hub method. How to avoid the re-connect issue. How Do I persist the things, even hub is not handle sessions.

Please suggest...

Answer (score 0):

inside your html, in first load, create a random id and store it in cookies.

In your hub code, create an arraylist and store these random ids with corresponding connection ID.

In your html, try to read the random id from the cookies during each page refresh, if it is not found, it's a new connection, if it is found, use the old random id with a new connection ID to connect to your hub.  Then in your hub arraylist, for this particular random id, replace the old connection ID with the new connection ID.

Comment: This will not work if the array is not declared static. And it won't fully solve the problem anyway because the array would be lost as soon as the app pool is recycled, which can happen anytime. It'd be ok most of the times but not always, however it might be good enough.

Comment: I use a heartbeat function in javascript to re-login if something happens to the connection and/or the signalr server, e.g. I can turn off the signalr Server and wait a few minutes, and turn it on again, then after a few seconds, everything comes back to normal

Comment: That's fine, and of course overall it works, I was just pointing out that you cannot fully avoid rechecking the login info, *which is what was asked in the OP*, and in general is not trivial to achieve.